# Copy a wav file

Tags: c, wav

I'm trying to copy a wave file, and create a new wave file with the same information. In other words: copy a wave file. I think the problem is the write of the datas sound.

I tried to write the data in different ways, but it didn't work.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE_HEADER_WAVE 44

typedef struct wave {
    char file_type_bloc_id[4];
    int32_t file_size;
    char file_format_id[4];
    char format_bloc_id[4];
    int32_t bloc_size;
    int16_t audio_format;
    int16_t nbr_channel;
    int32_t frequence;
    int32_t byte_per_sec;
    int16_t byte_per_bloc;
    int16_t byte_per_sample;
    char data_bloc_id[4];
    int32_t data_size;
    union {
        int8_t* data_ptr8;
        int16_t* data_ptr16;
        int32_t* data_ptr24;
    } data;
} wave_s;

wave_s* wave_load(const char* filename) {
    int read = 0;
    unsigned char buffer2[2];
    unsigned char buffer4[4];
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;

    wave_s* wave = malloc(sizeof(wave_s));

    // every information in th header of the first wave are copied into the second

    read = fread(wave->file_type_bloc_id, sizeof(wave->file_type_bloc_id), 1, file);

    read = fread(buffer4, sizeof(buffer4), 1, file);
    wave->file_size = buffer4[0] | (buffer4[1]<<8) | (buffer4[2]<<16) | (buffer4[3]<<24);

    read = fread(wave->file_format_id, sizeof(wave->file_format_id), 1, file);

    read = fread(wave->format_bloc_id, sizeof(wave->format_bloc_id), 1, file);

    read = fread(buffer4, sizeof(buffer4), 1, file);
    wave->bloc_size = buffer4[0] | (buffer4[1]<<8) | (buffer4[2]<<16) | (buffer4[3]<<24);

    read = fread(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), 1, file);
    wave->audio_format = buffer2[0] | (buffer2[1]<<8);

    fread(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), 1, file);
    wave->nbr_channel = buffer2[0] | (buffer2[1]<<8);

    fread(buffer4, sizeof(buffer4), 1, file);
    wave->frequence = buffer4[0] | (buffer4[1]<<8) | (buffer4[2]<<16) | (buffer4[3]<<24);

    fread(buffer4, sizeof(buffer4), 1, file);
    wave->byte_per_sec = buffer4[0] | (buffer4[1]<<8) | (buffer4[2]<<16) | (buffer4[3]<<24);

    fread(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), 1, file);
    wave->byte_per_bloc = buffer2[0] | (buffer2[1]<<8);

    fread(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), 1, file);
    wave->byte_per_sample = buffer2[0] | (buffer2[1]<<8);

    fread(wave->data_bloc_id, sizeof(wave->data_bloc_id), 1, file);

    fread(buffer4, sizeof(buffer4), 1, file);
    wave->data_size = buffer4[0] | (buffer4[1]<<8) | (buffer4[2]<<16) | (buffer4[3]<<24);        

    // writing datas
    if (wave->byte_per_sample == 8)
        wave->data.data_ptr8 = malloc(sizeof(int8_t) * wave->data_size);
    else if (wave->byte_per_sample == 16)
        wave->data.data_ptr16 = malloc(sizeof(int16_t) * wave->data_size);
    else if (wave->byte_per_sample == 24)
        wave->data.data_ptr24 = malloc(sizeof(int32_t) * wave->data_size);

    int nbr_sample = (8 * wave->data_size) / (wave->nbr_channel * wave->byte_per_sample);
    int length_sample = (wave->nbr_channel * wave->byte_per_sample) / 8;
    char data_buffer[length_sample];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nbr_sample; i++) {
        read = fread(data_buffer, sizeof(data_buffer), 1, file);
        if (read != 0) {
            int j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < wave->nbr_channel; j++) {
                if (wave->byte_per_sample == 8)
                wave->data.data_ptr8[i * length_sample] = data_buffer[0];
                else if (wave->byte_per_sample == 16)
                    wave->data.data_ptr16[i * length_sample] = data_buffer[0] | data_buffer[1]<<8;
                else if (wave->byte_per_sample == 24)
                    wave->data.data_ptr24[i * length_sample] =
                data_buffer[0] | (data_buffer[1]<<8) | (data_buffer[2]<<16) | (data_buffer[3]<<24);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return wave;
}

bool wave_save(const char* filename, wave_s* wave) {

    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    fwrite(wave, SIZE_HEADER_WAVE, 1, file);

    if (wave->byte_per_sample == 8)
        fwrite(wave->data.data_ptr8, wave->data_size, 1, file);
    else if (wave->byte_per_sample == 16)
        fwrite(wave->data.data_ptr16, wave->data_size, 1, file);
    else if (wave->byte_per_sample == 24)
        fwrite(wave->data.data_ptr24, wave->data_size, 1, file);

    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

int main() {
    wave_save("440-2.wav", wave_load("440.wav"));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In this program, I expect that the output wave file (here, it's name is "440-2.wav") is the same as "440.wav". But when I listen 440-2.wav after execute the program, it's not the same sound as "440.wav".

I thinks the problem is data sounds are not good copied from "440.wav" to "440-2.wav", but I don't know where the error can be.

Comment: Simply copying the file doesn't require you to understand its structure.  Presumably, though, the intent is that you do copy the file into an internal format such that it can be written back out without being significantly changed.

Comment: What is the unit of measurement of `data_size` in the structure?  Bytes, or number of samples?  How does this correlate with `file_size`?  My suspicion is that the code you represent by `[...]` might be important.  How do you read the data into the header?  Do you have to worry about big-endian vs little-endian encoding for the file header?  You've also omitted some global variables and some other stuff.  Please reread about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and make this into one.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? Do you just want to make a verbatim copy of the wav file? If yes, your question boils down to "how can I make a copy of a file".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is right, I didn't need to completely understand the structure to copy. But, later, my goal is to make some operation like add a chanel, reverse a wave ... and for this, I need to understand the structure. This is why, for copy, I do this code.
The unit of measure of `data_size` is octets. This is the size of the data, without the header. So we have `file_size = data_size + header_size - 8`. The -8 comes from the norm of how a header of a wave file is describes.
I think I don't have to worry about endianess because I just copy datas. So I don't have to check endianess.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output a huge number of messages.   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Comment: @Mathemataume I'm not faulting you since you probably didn't foresee the misunderstanding of intent, but for future reference, you should use the keywords _parse_ and _serialize_ if you mean to do more than just copy the file opaquely.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm trying to create a programm to do dome operations on wave file like reverse, accelerate... To do that, I need to import a file in my programm and then create a new wave file from my programm, where I did sme modifications. So this is not just a copy (well as this point this is just a copy, but I mean this is not the final goal).

You were write my code was not an MCVE, I edit it and did modifications needed.

Comment: Is the `.wav` file you're reading encoded with 24 bits per sample?  It looks like you process 24 bits per sample 32 bits at a time, which would then distort your copied data.  I'd expect to see you read 3 bytes (24 bits) and decode them.  Your code indicates that the data is stored on disk in little-endian format (you place the first of two bytes as the least significant byte of a 16-bit sample, and similarly, but perhaps too enthusiastically, with the 24-bit samples).  I've not studied the `.wav` specification (where is it?), so I don't know whether I'm deducing anything relevant.

Comment: you probably should read/understand the [wave format](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/)   and [wave format](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html)